# What does OilMarketCube mean?

Tags: petroleum-engineering

I don't understand p 24 of [this PDF](https://www.rystadenergy.com/globalassets/pdfs/rystad-energy_covid-19-report_14_may_2020-public-version.pdf) from [Rystad Energy](https://www.rystadenergy.com/newsevents/news/press-releases/covid-19-demand-update-oil-seen-down-10point9-jet-fuel-down-33point6-road-fuel-down-11point1-in-2020flat/). Can someone please distinguish, and ELI5, 7 ((Crude supply (current OilMarketCube, downside risk)) and 8 (Crude supply (with required shut-ins to balance))?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precise definition of Oilmarket cube will be explained elsewhere, earlier most likely, but it will be a unit that is used to  compare sources much like kWh can be used for gas as a cubic foot of gas varies its heating power with temperature.

It could be 1m^3 or 1000m^3 but it will be an amount stated.